# UBUNTU not loading in asus rog

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu in my Asus ROG laptop(GL552VW). After selecting the option to load Ubuntu in boot menu , its starts to load ubuntu but before the boot completes the system stops working and freezes . Is the problem with nvidia drivers , if so how can you change the code without booting ubuntu

i have tried it on ubuntu(14.4,16.4,18.4,16.10 debian etc) and still all of them freezes without completing the boot. There are many solutions to update the graphic driver commands but all of them require the ubuntu to boot. There are many links to update the drivers but all of them require the ubuntu to boot.

I tried using many techniques but none of them worked , no matter what i do the boot won't complete.
Can someone please help me install ubuntu in my system.

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset`.